# AWK removal of lines in CSV with two empty fields?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I rarely use awk and I think I'm forgetting a basic of using it with CSV files, here, but I have the following file, called new2.csv:

```
Filename,Dist.(ft),BR Name,BR 2-Way Time,Till/WBR Name,Till/WBR 2-Way Time
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.042,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.083,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.125,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.167,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.208,BR,92.58,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.25,BR,,Till/WBR,29.3
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.292,BR,,Till/WBR,
```

I would like to only retain the rows that have values in the fourth or sixth column (lines 7 and 8) using awk.

I tried a few things to check what's going on in there:

```
awk -F',' '{print NR, "->", $4}' new2.csv
```

returns line 7 -> 92.58 for line 7 and nothing for the rest of the lines, so that's good.  Next, I tried

```
awk -F',' '{print NR, "->", $6}' new2.csv
```

which returns line 8 -> 29.3, so we're still good.

Thinking I have it solved, I move on to

```
awk -F',' '$4!=""' new2.csv
```

and it prints the header line and the seventh line of the code, as expected.  Moving on to column 6, I write the same expression and it returns the entire contents of new2.csv.  In attempt to troubleshoot, I try

```
awk -F',' '{print NR, "->", $6!=""}' new2.csv
```

and that returns line 1 -> 1, line2 -> 1, ..., line 8 ->1, ...etc, so there's my problem.  What's going on?  Is there a way I can fix it?

The comma at the end of the line seems like it might be the source of the problem, but after reading quite a few posts I'm still not sure what to do about it.  `awk '{print substr($0,0,length($0)-1)}' new.csv` doesn't remove the last comma either.  I generated the csv on a Windows 8 machine and am using awk on a Linux box in bash.

Comment: have values both in 4th and 6th columns?

Comment: Your sample input has no lines that have values in the 4th and 6th columns. `FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.208,BR,92.58,Till/WBR,` has `92.58` in the 4th column, but nothing in the 6th, while `FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.25,BR,,Till/WBR,29.3` has `29.3` in the 6th but nothing in the 4th and none of the others have values either place.

Comment: Yes, all lines in the data set have $1, $2, $3, and $5 values.  Some lines also have either $4 or $6 values, but no line (except for the header) will have both $4 && $6 values.  The end goal is to write a new file that consists of only the lines that have a value in either the fourth or sixth column.  Just edited above to clarify - thanks for catching it.

Comment: Ok then change all the "and"s to "or"s in your question. Should the new file include the header line or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '($4$6)~/./' file
Filename,Dist.(ft),BR Name,BR 2-Way Time,Till/WBR Name,Till/WBR 2-Way Time
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.208,BR,92.58,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.25,BR,,Till/WBR,29.3
```

or if you want fields that contain only spaces to be considered "empty" too:

```
$ awk -F, '($4$6)~/[^[:space:]]/' file
Filename,Dist.(ft),BR Name,BR 2-Way Time,Till/WBR Name,Till/WBR 2-Way Time
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.208,BR,92.58,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.25,BR,,Till/WBR,29.3
```

and if you want to exclude the header line:

```
$ awk -F, '(NR>1) && (($4$6)~/[^[:space:]]/)' file
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.208,BR,92.58,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.25,BR,,Till/WBR,29.3
```

Comment: can you please explain `[^[:space:]]`?  +1 for the simple and clean answer!

Comment: `[:space:]` is a POSIX character class that represents any space character (blank, tab, formfeed, newline, etc.) and so `[^[:space:]]` is a POSIX bracket expression that means `not a space`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Filename,Dist.(ft),BR Name,BR 2-Way Time,Till/WBR Name,Till/WBR 2-Way Time FILE____007P_1.DZT,0,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.042,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.083,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.125,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.167,BR,,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.208,BR,92.58,Till/WBR,
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.25,BR,,Till/WBR,29.3
FILE____007P_1.DZT,0.292,BR,,Till/WBR,

hzhang@dell-work ~ $ cat test.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN{
    FS = ","
}
{
    # ignore the first definition line
    if(FNR > 1){
        # checks column 4 has a non-empty value
        if($4 !=""){
            print FNR,"->", $4
        }

        # checks column 6 has a non-empty value
        if($6 != ""){
            print FNR,"->", $6
        }

    }
}
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ awk -f test.awk sample.csv 
6 -> 92.58
7 -> 29.3
```

if you want to run command line on console:

```
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ awk -F, '(FNR>1){if($4 != ""){ print FNR,"->",$4  }; if($6 != ""){ print FNR,"->",$6  }}' sample.csv 
6 -> 92.58
7 -> 29.3
```

Comment: This works, although I don't understand why it doesn't suffer the same problem as the `awk -F',' '{print NR, "->", $6!=""}' new2.csv` line?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up patterns and actions.

`awk -F',' '$4!=""'` is a pattern without action, it says "do default if `$4` is empty". Default action is print input.

`awk -F',' '{print NR, "->", $6!=""}'` is an action without pattern. Missing pattern makes all line match for the action. It says -- print line number, then `->`, then result of comparing `$6` to "empty" (which is a boolean 0 or 1, 1 for "true").

To do what you want, you can use bare pattern:

```
awk -F, '$4!="" || $6!=""'
```

This says - "do default action of `$4` is not empty, or `$6` is not empty". Default action is print input.

Or you can use bare action:

```
awk -F, '{ if ($4 != "" || $6 != "") { print $0; } }'
```

This one says - evaluate if `$4` is not empty, or `$6` is not empty then print `$0` (which is input line).

P.S. From your question and actions, it's not clear whether you want lines that have both 4th and 6th not empty, or just one. If it's both, then the tests about should be and (`&&`) instead of or (`||`)

Comment: Hi Pawel, I began with the bare pattern that includes the OR statement that you point out.  Once I noticed that it had returned all lines, I decided to print the results of each to screen was to figure out what was happening. The output for `awk -F',' '$4!=""'` was line 7, as expected, but the output for `awk -F',' '$6!=""'` returns all of the lines rather than just line 8.  Sorry for the confusion - my next step, once I've successfully designed a line of code that produces only line 8 when I'm looking at $6, will definitely involve the || and I will print the results to a new file.

Comment: @k.mat27 if `$6!=""` prints all lines then your other lines have trailing spaces at the end of them. Use `$6~/[^[:space:]]/` instead.